# How to get the user login/logoff time using Python for osx or macos

Tags: python, macos

I am working on a project where, I have to get logoff, logon, lock, unlock, console connect, disconnect, service start/stop using python. Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Are you talking about operating system event logging? Meaning, the timestamps when a user logs on or off interactively?

Comment: `start/stop using python`, I thought he was referring to the use of python but I got downvoted so I guess he just wants the last boot time, login time,...

Comment: If you don't give us more details, we won't be able to answer your question correctly.

Comment: @DanielPryden, ya you are right, but using python

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte, the thing is that I want to track the employee activity like when they are going for break and how long i.e lock and unlock time with user name. similarly logon and logoff time for the user using python.

Comment: The thing is, macOS doesn't run on Python so you will have to interact with the system somehow anyway.

Comment: Note that extensive tracking of employee activity is illegal in a lot of countries.

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte Actually I m absolute beginner and need to make it as a service or convert in .exe file

Comment: You can check my answer, it goes in details on two possibilities you have. They can be used in Python but you must have a basic knowledge of the way macOS handles users and how to parse a command output or a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `last` UNIX command and [call it from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python).
It will give you logoff, logon, console connect/disconnect, boot, reboot, shutdown. `last Jhon` to see Jhon's history, `last reboot` to see reboot history.

You can also use the `~/.zsh_history` or `~/.bash_history` file if you want to see the use of the console, it contains timestamps relative to EPOCH time. It might be better than raw login/logoff times since you can have an open prompt and type nothing in it.

Comment: Pilatte, Last command is producing reboot and shutdown, But I need switch user activity (i.e when users are changing their shift)

Comment: `last jhon` gives you all login history for `jhon`, which is what you want.

Comment: Pilatte, Thanks for your quick reply, it's working like charm. CAN you suggest something similar for screen lock/Unlock

Comment: To my knowledge, that is not recorded. Simply because there is no such thing as screen locked/unlocked to the kernel.

Comment: I mean need to capture lock screen time